# disable button based on time using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Hi i have to disable button button based on date,my requirement is i will have json that are having values checkinStartDate and checkinEndDate**

```
{
    "checkinStartDate": "10/22/2016 09:10:04 AM",
    "checkinEndDate": "10/22/2016 19:10:04 PM"
}
```

For example today's date is 10/22/2016 then condition is mentioned below. 
I have to enable button before **1 hr(10/22/2016 08:10:04 AM)** of checkinStartDate and **1 hr(10/22/2016 20:10:04 PM)** after checkinEndDate.other than this time button should be in disabled mode
 Any help will be greatfull.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo yes it is dynamic

Comment: Maybe you could use setTimeout() after you check your JSON and get the time the app need to wait.  When the setTimeout is trigged you can put your  disable variable to true and disable the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your object is assigned to $scope.date
Then what you need to do next is.

```
$scope.checkDate = function () {
  var ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000; /* ms */
  var myDate = {
    "checkinStartDate": "10/22/2016 09:10:04 AM",
    "checkinEndDate": "10/22/2016 19:10:04 PM"
  }

  var checkInStart = new Date(myDate.checkinStartDate);
  var checkInEnd = new Date(myDate.checkinEndDate);

  var current = new Date();

  //only enable during this time
  if ((current.getTime() < checkInStart.getTime() + ONE_HOUR) && (current.getTime() + ONE_HOUR > checkInEnd.getTime()))
    return false;


  //otherwhile disable  
  return true;
}
```

In the view, just call it

```
<button ng-disabled="checkDate()">View<button>
```

p/s: it is just the idea, I am not sure my condition is correct because I don't have the environment for testing. the getTime() will return you the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970, and a specified date. Then you can use it to compare 1 hour ahead of before. You see what I am saying ?

Comment: HI thanks for your suggestion, but i am getting invalid date for checkInEnd

Comment: getting invalid date for checkinEndDate

Comment: How is this going Sudhir ?